# In PySpark/Spark dataframe join, how to update column values only when there is a match found?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am joining two dataframes: `customer`, `price`

customer dataframe schema:

```
customer:
 root
 |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C_CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C_OPTION: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C_MATERIAL: string(10,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- CID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CUSTOMER_EXPENSES: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CUSTOMER_LOCATION: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PRODUCT_NAME: string (nullable = true)
```

price dataframe schema:

```
price:
 root
 |-- PRICE_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PRICE_CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PRICE_RANGE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C_MATERIAL: string(10,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- CID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PRICE_DEFAULT: int (nullable = true)
 |-- PRODUCT_LOCATION: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PRODUCT_NAME: string (nullable = true)
```

I have the keys `price.PRICE_CODE == customer.C_CODE` & `price.PRODUCT_LOCATION == customer.CUSTOMER_LOCATION` to join the tables.

case 1: If there is a matching record in the price dataset per `PRICE_CODE`, `PRODUCT_LOCATION` then use `CUSTOMER_EXPENSES` from the customer dataset in a new column.

case 2: If there is no match, then use average of the column: `PRICE_DEFAULT` in the same new column.

I used `left` join to join price and customer tables. So the keys of customer table: `C_CODE` & `CUSTOMER_LOCATION` will be NULL if there is no match.

I joined them in the below fashion:

```
join_df = price.join(customer, on=(price['PRICE_CODE'] == customer['C_CODE']) & (price['PRODUCT_LOCATION'] == customer['CUSTOMER_LOCATION']), how='left')
```

I have taken the average of PRICE_DEFAULT from price table as below.

```
price_avg = str(join_df.select(avg('PRICE_DEFAULT')).collect()[0][0]
```

Now I will have all key entries from price table and NULLs from customer table that are not matching.

case 1 implementation:

```
price.join(customer, on=(price['PRICE_CODE'] == customer['C_CODE']) & (price['PRODUCT_LOCATION'] == customer['CUSTOMER_LOCATION']), how='left')
.drop(price.PRODUCT_NAME)\
.withColumn('derived', 
   when((col('PRICE_CODE').isNotNull()) & (col('PRODUCT_LOCATION').isNotNull()), customer.CUSTOMER_EXPENSES)
```

Case 2 implementation:

```
price.join(customer, on=(price['PRICE_CODE'] == customer['C_CODE']) & (price['PRODUCT_LOCATION'] == customer['CUSTOMER_LOCATION']), how='left')
.drop(price.PRODUCT_NAME)\
.withColumn('derived', 
   when((col('PRICE_CODE').isNotNull()) & (col('PRODUCT_LOCATION').isNotNull()), customer.CUSTOMER_EXPENSES).\
   when((col('C_CODE').isNull()) & (col('CUSTOMER_LOCATION').isNull()), price_avg)
```

I am facing a problem here.
When the columns `PRICE_CODE` & `PRODUCT_LOCATION` are not null, I am seeing the values in the new column: `derived` as expected. i.e. value of `customer.CUSTOMER_EXPENSES`

But when the columns `C_CODE` & `CUSTOMER_LOCATION` are NULL, instead of the average value, I still see the value of `customer.CUSTOMER_EXPENSES`

Sample output:

The rows marked in yellow (rows 18-24) are coming out fine. But the rows marked in red (rows 2-17) are still containing the same values of `PRICE_DEFAULT` instead of the `price_avg = AVERAGE(PRICE_DEFAULT)`

[image]

Am I applying the JOIN+WHEN conditions correctly for cases 1 & 2?
Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I can fix it. Any suggestions or help is really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the `lit` function from `pyspark.sql.functions`? In your second `when` of `case2`, you can write `lit(price_avg)`. 

P.S: In the `case2` implementation, you don't need the second `when`, you can just use the `.otherwise(lit(price_avg))`

Comment: Isn’t lit a constant for every row of that column? I need average to be populated if the first condition is not satisfied.

Comment: could you show you data in plaintext *including* `CUSTOMER_EXPENSES` column?  and also a sample input in plain text? 

and can you check if your `C_CODE`, `PRODUCT_LOCATION`, `CUSTOMER_LOCATION` is null or empty string?

Comment: @Metadata As Rehan mentioned, you can just use this, 
```price.join(customer, on=(price['PRICE_CODE'] == customer['C_CODE']) & (price['PRODUCT_LOCATION'] == customer['CUSTOMER_LOCATION']), how='left')
.drop(price.PRODUCT_NAME)\
.withColumn('derived', 
   when((col('PRICE_CODE').isNotNull()) & (col('PRODUCT_LOCATION').isNotNull()), customer.CUSTOMER_EXPENSES).otherwise(lit(price_avg)))```


This will first check the when condition and if True `CUSTOMER_EXPENSES` will pe populated and if False it will use the `price_avg`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few issues here:

1. The combination of `price.PRICE_CODE` and `price.PRICE_DEFAULT` is apparently not unique (judging from your picture). This will lead to duplication in the case of a successful join, and I'm not sure whether that's indended.
2. "I am facing a problem here. When the columns `PRICE_CODE` & `PRODUCT_LOCATION` are not null, I am seeing the values in the new column `derived` as expected. i.e. value of `customer.CUSTOMER_EXPENSES`" The `customer.CUSTOMER_EXPENSES` column is not visible in the image you provided. However, in the rows marked red, if there are no matching rows on the right hand side of the join, where would the values of `customer.CUSTOMER_EXPENSES` even come from? Something is off. It almost seems like in the image the `derived` column is actually derived from `price.PRICE_DEFAULT`, not from `customer.CUSTOMER_EXPENSES`. Are you sure that your posted code produces these exact results? Since you're writing "are still containing the same values of `PRICE_DEFAULT`" (which should read `CUSTOMER_EXPENSES`), perhaps the column names get mixed up somewhere in the process?
3. The duplicate `when()` statements are not required; an `otherwise()` in place of the second `when()` is sufficient in your case. However, there's an even simpler solution available using `coalesce()`. Using `join_df` from your definiton, simply do

```py
price_avg = join_df.select(f.avg("PRICE_DEFAULT")).collect()[0][0] # no string conversion required

result = join_df.drop(price.PRODUCT_NAME).withColumn(
    "derived", f.coalesce(f.col("CUSTOMER_EXPENSES"), f.lit(price_avg))
) # takes the first non-null column, i.e. a price_avg literal for rows with no match
```

Comment: From the second code snippet, `Which should work` -> That was a spelling mistake which I corrected. But it doesn't work. Also my data volume is huge, the last aproach will eat up memory and time.

Comment: I've expanded my answer. All versions work fine for me with some basic test data. Could you provide some data or be more specific about the results/errors you're getting?

Comment: There is no error in the execution. The logic applied in WHEN condition for ISNOTNULL is working but logic in WHEN IS NULL is not. Instead of populating the average value, it is just keeping the value in new column same as it is. i.e. NULL

Comment: I have checked your image and fully rewritten my answer. I'm not certain whether it's actually possible to produce the exact results you're seeing with the exact code you provided. If so, it would be great to see some of the input data to reproduce the issue.